# How to handle a price change in DB just when a customer is placing an order online?

Tags: mysql, database, e-commerce, race-condition, consistency

I have a `Product` database table with columns such as `product_id`, `price`, and `inventory_count`.

A user clicks to buy a certain product at a certain price. My program generates a confirmation page listing the product and the price. Everything is fine and the user clicks "Confirm". My program updates the `inventory_count` of that product and charges the user's credit card the amount listed in the product's `price`.

But during the time after the confirmation page is generated but before the user clicks "Confirm", the price of that product has been changed. So the user might have seen a price of $10 in the confirmation page but after he clicks "Confirm" the `price` in the Product table has already been changed to $11 and that's what he will be charged.

What's the best way to handle a situation like this? I'm using  MySQL and Python if that's relevant.

Comment: Hmmm... interesting situation. I would keep the prices in the user's cart (client side) and compare prices with the server side on the page that's doing the credit processing. If there's a difference, redirect the user to a new page saying "prices have changed".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a new table for pending purchases with the price you intend to actually charge, and add items to it when you generate the confirmation page.

Deduct from the `Product` table's `inventory_count` when you add an item to the `Pending` table, then you can re-increment the `inventory_count` if the purchase doesn't go through.

Answer (score 4):

You definitely should carry over the price from the time the customer last had the chance to change his mind. I'm sure that's also a legal issue in which you'd not look so good.

Anyway, can't be to hard to implement one last check after the customer has confirmed, right? Maybe you then could show a notice that the price has changed.

Answer (score 2):

I my opinion you should avoid situations like this (if I were your customer I would be disappointed).
But if you can't, when customer press confirm, do the last check of price and show message to user if it changed.